# How to Notify IEnumerable

Tags: .net, wpf, binding, ienumerable

When App.StaticLib.Search.SearchDetail is changed I call NotifyPropertyChanged on the collection.

```
public enumSearchDetail SearchDetail
{
    get { return searchDetail; }
    set
    {
        if (searchDetail == value) return;
        searchDetail = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("SearchDetail");
        NotifyPropertyChanged("SearchFieldsListCurrent");                    
    }
}
```

But that does not cause UI elements bound to SearchFieldsListCurrent to get a fresh IEnumerable
It is a Collection but I can't figure out how to manually call a NotifyCollectionChanged

```
public IEnumerable<FieldDef> SearchFieldsListCurrent
{
    get
    {
        if (App.StaticLib.Search.SearchDetail == enumSearchDetail.Basic) return SearchFieldsListBasic;
        if (App.StaticLib.Search.SearchDetail == enumSearchDetail.Advanced) return SearchFieldsListAdvanced;
        else return SearchFieldsList;
    }
    set { NotifyPropertyChanged("SearchFieldsListCurrent"); }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide the code where you call `NotifyPropertyChanged("SearchFieldsListCurrent");`?

Comment: @mrzli OK but you really need to see the SearchDetail set?  I stated I notify when it is changed.  Yes the set on SearchFieldsListCurrent does something - it calls NotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: if you are using a listview or a listbox try (Items.Refresh())

Comment: I tried some code with the same logic you have, and it updated the gui control without a problem. I used ListBox in my test. So this should work. I'm guessing `SearchDetail` property is in the same class as `SearchFieldsListCurrent` property :)?

Comment: @mrzli it is bound to ComboBox and they are in the same class.  It is from a separate class library that is instantiated in App.

Comment: @Blam Ok, so I tried with ComboBox and it works again. Sorry for asking what might be stupid questions, but I don't get what you said in last comment. What is from a separate class library? You have `SearchFieldsListCurrent` in a class, let me call it "ClassWithProperties". Then again you have `SearchDetail` which is again as you said in "ClassWithProperties". And then you have `App.StaticLib.Search.SearchDetail` which is in a separate class, right? What is strange to me is why do you use `App.StaticLib.Search.SearchDetail` instead of only `SearchDetail`?

Comment: @mrzli Since it is a separate class is is maybe why it is not working for me.  In the the project I added a class and in that file are the above.  In App I new that class. SearchDetail is not available directly as it is not static.  The plan is to reuse this in a web service.  Maybe that was not a good plan but that is the plan.

Comment: @Blam I believe I can help you solve your problem and elegantly, but I still don't understand what is where. Can you answer the following two questions with yes or no: 1. Are both properties in your question in the same class, and there is a separate `App.StaticLib.Search.SearchDetail` property? 2. `SearchDetail` is `App.StaticLib.Search.SearchDetail` and it is a separate class from `SearchFieldsListCurrent`?

Comment: @mrzli Valid questions and the design may not be optimal.  Both are in the same class.  I will post the App.cs ctor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to refresh your UI manually

```
ComboBox1.Items.Refresh();
```

or

```
ComboBox1.ItemsSource=null;
ComboBox1.ItemsSource=SearchFieldsListCurrent;
```

Comment: I was hoping to manually force a collection changed but the second worked.  Refresh did not.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, based on our discussion in the question comments, this is how I would do it:

In the class that you bind to your gui/control (I will call it your viewmodel):

```
public enumSearchDetail SearchDetail
{
    get { return App.StaticLib.Search.SearchDetail; }
    set
    {
        if (App.StaticLib.Search.SearchDetail == value) return;
        App.StaticLib.Search.SearchDetail = value;

        // note that you can comment out these 2 lines if you use the event I describe at the end of this answer
        // since these 2 NotifyPropertyChanged would be called immediately when value is set to "App.StaticLib.Search.SearchDetail"
        NotifyPropertyChanged("SearchDetail");
        NotifyPropertyChanged("SearchFieldsListCurrent");                    
    }
}

public IEnumerable<FieldDef> SearchFieldsListCurrent
{
    get
    {
        if (SearchDetail == enumSearchDetail.Basic) return SearchFieldsListBasic;
        if (SearchDetail == enumSearchDetail.Advanced) return SearchFieldsListAdvanced;
        else return SearchFieldsList;
    }

    // I don't know the rest of your code, but I don't get what possible use could this setter have,
    // it sets no value and does nothing except trigger NotifyPropertyChanged("SearchFieldsListCurrent")
    // when you execute "SearchFieldsListCurrent = <some_value>;"
    // if you want to trigger that you can and should always do so directly, not like described above
    // set { NotifyPropertyChanged("SearchFieldsListCurrent"); }
}
```

Anyway, you don't need the backing field for `SearchDetail`, you already store that value in `App.StaticLib.Search.SearchDetail`. If you change search detail using this `SearchDetail` property in the viewmodel (or using your gui which in turn should again update this property), it will also update `App.StaticLib.Search.SearchDetail`, and trigger required NotifyPropertyChanged() so everything should work in this situation.

For the situation where change occurs directly in `App.StaticLib.Search.SearchDetail`, I suggest adding some event to `App.StaticLib.Search` which you would use from your viewmodel like this.

In the constructor of your viewmodel (or whereever is appropriate) you can subscribe to this event:

```
App.StaticLib.Search.SearchDetailChanged += SearchDetailChangedHandler;
```

And again in your viewmodel you have the handler for it which would look something like this:

```
private void SearchDetailChangedHandler()
{
    NotifyPropertyChanged("SearchDetail");
    NotifyPropertyChanged("SearchFieldsListCurrent");  
}
```

So if you change `App.StaticLib.Search.SearchDetail` directly, it will also update your gui.
(Don't forget to raise this event inside `App.StaticLib.Search.SearchDetail` setter).

Answer (score 0):

DataGrid reflects changes on **NotifyCollectionChanged**. For that use **ObservableCollection<>** instead of IEnumerable<>. If you dont want to do that and want it to be done only with List or IEnumerable then return **new instance of List** every time from the getter of property and then fire PropertyChanged, this is kind of tricky but worked for me .

Comment: But I don't bind to a DataGrid.  I bind to ComboBox.   And I tried ObservableCollection but it still does not work as I am not changing the collection - I only want another collection to be return.  Can you give me a sample of new instance of List every time?

Comment: Yes it doesnot work for ComboBox .I checked the code It works for DataGrid because It was loaded again .But for ObservableCollection it works and in that we have to keep in mind that we dont change its instance we need to clear and add in the same instance of observable collection.